# Android Broken Shortcut After Update

Tags: android, shortcut, android-launcher

Launcher/Main activity was changed in the manifest and after the update users using custom OS Launchers (ie: dodol Launcher) report their shortcuts broken with message "App isnt installed".

This is a big problem as many just uninstall the app in confusion.

To my understanding whats happening is that the launcher captures some additional info about the shortcut, and when it sees a mismatch with the starter activity in the manifest it thinks app isnt there any more.

This is obviously a custom launcher issue, but seems wide spread enough to need a work around for this.

I am experimenting with setting both old & new activities as MAIN/LAUNCHER to see if this has any impact.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue, and if so any recommended strategies on tackling this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found answer to this?

Comment: There does not seem to be a solution for this. Reason being is that when short cuts are created some custom launchers include additional meta data from the manifest. With some custom launchers this problem surfaces when you change starter activity.

Comment: I found solution yesterday, it works in my testing. Maybe not going to work for all custom launchers but it does work for couple I tested. See my answer

Comment: That was my experience as well, that the solution was not 100% bullet proof when it comes to custom launchers. I tried with a number of different launchers and Dodol Launcher was the biggest offender, I would use it for testing. But again it's not definitive.

Comment: @katit answer is valid, Just wanted to share with you those article [Never change your launcher activity. Ever](http://andrzejchm.github.io/android/never_change_your_launcher_activity/) and [Preserve Your Launchers: Use Activity Aliases](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/01/16/preserve-your-launchers-use-activity-alias/) that are tackling the same problem, and all the steps are are described in more details.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved this. I had `LoginActivity` as a main launch activity:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

We had to redo some of the logic, mainly how our MAIN activity get's started. We ended up creating dummy `LauncherActivity` and take user either to inside of app or to the `LoginActivity`. So, after that was done we got exact same issue after upgrade. Luckily I caught it before release. "App not installed".

Solution. Use `activity-alias`, Took some tinkering and I'm not 100% sure if we needed to rename `LoginActivity` or not. But we did rename it to `SignInActivity` and here is end config in manifest which works for us.

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LauncherActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />

        <!-- Don't brake 2.7.2->3.0.0 shortcuts, keep ALIAS for old way to access app -->
        <activity-alias android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" android:targetActivity=".activities.LauncherActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity android:name=".activities.SignInActivity" />
```

Point here - we do keep old signature and but "reroute" launchers to use our new `LauncherActivity`